# Setting up raspberry pi camera to view on a Web page

Tags: raspbian, networking

I really need help some with getting my raspberry pi  camera set up to view online. I am running the most current version of raspbian, and everything is updated/upgraded. I have a preloaded SD with NOOBS, and haven't had any success with motion when I download with terminal. I do have another SD card that I loaded with motion eye, which works on my local network, but no matter what I do with port forwarding and DDNS, I can't make remote connection. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by `haven't had any success with motion when I download with terminal.` ?

Comment: I mean I haven't been able to get motion to install properly when I've tried downloading through the command line.

Comment: What commands are you using to get/install it and what error(s) are you seeing.

Comment: I have been trying to use the most recent tutorial i could find, which is  http://garyhall.org.uk/raspberry-pi-internet-enabled-camera.html. I can get through all the tutorial steps, until i come to the last one, which is supposed to start the camera. ./mjpg_streamer -o "output_http.so -w ./www"-i "input_raspicam.so" At this point I end up getting an error that says that no such file or directory exists.

Comment: I will try that when I get off work. Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, I just followed the steps on the [tutorial you pointed to](http://garyhall.org.uk/raspberry-pi-internet-enabled-camera.html).
I am running it on a Model B+ with a Raspberry Pi Camera attached.

I found a few issues with it.

1. It instructs the user to install `libjpeg62-dev`. This is not available on Jessie and should be replaced with `libjpeg9-dev`. (`sudo apt-get install libjpeg9-dev`)
2. It doesn't specifically tell the user to make sure they are in the correct directory before running the `make`. You should be in `mjpg-streamer/mjpg-streamer-experimental`
3. If you copy the and paste the final command it likely will not work as there is no space between the `www"` and the `-i`. Make sure you have a space between these.

I suspect the `no such file or directory exists` error you are getting is because the build failed (because of the jpeg library). Just install `libjpeg9-dev` and try the steps from there again. 
If it still fails then please edit the question and add the output of `ls -l` and the exact output you get from the final command.

Comment: That did it! I was able to get the camera up and running! Now i want to stream it online. I downloaded ngrok and I there is supposed to be a forwarding URL, but i do not see one.

Comment: Figured out the ngrok issue. You have to sign up, and they provide an authorization code. @KennetRunner Thank you so much for all your help!!

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to put your camera online is [UV4L](http://linux-projects.org). In particular there is a pre-built Raspbian-based image with all the stuff pre-installed which allows you to get a video and/or audio stream from any browser, smartphone with no additional plugin required. UV4L is highly optimized for web streaming over internet as it can provide, other than MJPEG, also H264 or VP8 encoded video at variable bitrate.

Comment: UV4L is a good suggestion WRT the general theme of the question, but note you *don't* need a special "Raspbian based image", or any special plugin, in order to use the HTTP stream -- it is available in the normal distribution.

Comment: UV4L is also available as a standalone debian package.